# Configuring my sinatra app. Using Bundler and Sass

Tags: sinatra

So my `config.ru` in my Sinatra app looks like this, and I'm wondering if anything is redundant:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

require 'sass/plugin/rack'

Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
use Sass::Plugin::Rack

require File.expand_path('app.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))

run Sinatra::Application
```

What is the point of the `rubygem` and the `bundler` line on top? Can't I just run `bundle install` before running `rackup`? What's the point? Do I need these 3 lines? Why would I need them?

Also, I'm using sass for my project. I barely understand middleware. What are the `sass`-related lines doing? On a high level, why does `Sass` need to come from Rack?

I think I get the last two lines. I'm requiring my main file which is just called `app.rb` on the top level and I'm running Sinatra. That's fine.

If it's helpful, here's a snippet of my tree:

```
tree
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── app.rb
├── config.ru
├── lib
│   ├── accounting_service.rb
│   ├── distributor.rb
│   ├── house_distributor.rb
│   ├── mixer.rb
│   ├── mixer_worker.rb
│   └── transaction_service.rb
├── public
│   ├── images
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rubygems'
```

When you require rubygems the kernel method `require` is monkey patched so that ruby libraries that were installed with `gem install` can be found. You probable installed bundler like this so it is to find bundler on the next line this is needed.

```
require 'bundler'
```

Well you need to require bundle to use it on the next line.

```
Bundler.require
```

This line looks in your `Gemfiles` and requires everything in it. If you don't do it `sinatra` for example won't be found. If you want to you can replace the bundler stuff with explicit requires of the things you need. Not recommended though.

```
require 'sass/plugin/rack'

Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
use Sass::Plugin::Rack
```

This is a plugin to rack that turns your sass files into css and you have configured it to compress the resulting CSS. Performance for the win.

Comment: When I remove the require bundler and rubygems and Bundler require lines, I can still run my app on local host. Any idea why?

Comment: it depends on how you run it. I normally run sinatra with `bundler exec ruby <app.rb>` and then bundler loads libraries from the `Gemfile` for you. On the server though you probably run unicorn or similar and then it may be needed.